# Is there a built-in IEqualityComparer<T> for System.Int32?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, .net-standard

We are currently using `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` as the default way to initialize a generic dictionary. However, it crashes on Xamarin.iOS with the following error when the key of a dictionary is type `int` (but works on many other platforms I have tried):

> Attempting to JIT compile method `Lucene.Net.Support.LurchTable2<Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.FacetLabel, Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.Directory.DirectoryTaxonomyReader/Int32Class>:InternalInsert<Lucene.Net.Support.LurchTable2/Add2Info<Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.FacetLabel, Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.Directory.DirectoryTaxonomyReader/Int32Class>> (int,Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.FacetLabel,int&,Lucene.Net.Support.LurchTable/Add2Info<Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.FacetLabel, Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.Directory.DirectoryTaxonomyReader/Int32Class>)` while running in aot-only mode. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ for more information.
>
> at Lucene.Net.Support.LurchTable2[TKey,TValue].Insert[T] (TKey key, T& value) <0x2570f48 + 0x000e0> in <063e095c95d945a4ace32ab83d1227eb#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at (wrapper unknown) System.Object.gsharedvt_in() at Lucene.Net.Support.LurchTable2[TKey,TValue].AddOrUpdate (TKey key, TValue addValue, Lucene.Net.Support.KeyValueUpdate2[TKey,TValue] fnUpdate) <0x232824c + 0x0013b> in <063e095c95d945a4ace32ab83d1227eb#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.LRUHashMap2[TKey,TValue].Put (TKey key, TValue value) <0x2c487f8 + 0x0015b> in <79d3a7b905954d0993025c09c5d087ce#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.Directory.DirectoryTaxonomyReader.GetOrdinal (Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.FacetLabel cp) <0x2c51970 + 0x0019b> in <79d3a7b905954d0993025c09c5d087ce#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at Lucene.Net.Facet.Taxonomy.Int32TaxonomyFacets.GetTopChildren (System.Int32 topN, System.String dim, System.String[] path) <0x2c481dc + 0x0008f> in <79d3a7b905954d0993025c09c5d087ce#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at Login.MyMB.Lucene.Client.LuceneArticoliSearcher.GetListaArticoloXRicercaAvanzataConRicercaSemplice (System.Collections.Generic.List1[T] listParametri) <0x224add0 + 0x001bb> in <8f49891e0f0546e185aba7424d294ef7#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at Login.MyMB.Lucene.Client.LuceneArticoliSearcher.GetListaArticoloConRicercaSemplice (System.Collections.Generic.List1[T] listParametri) <0x224afbc + 0x0009f> in <8f49891e0f0546e185aba7424d294ef7#2ae0fea9ea4eacaef83bf2e9713bb8ea>:0 at MyMB.Forms.RicercaLucene.RicercaArticoloLucene.GetListaArticoliXRicercaSemplice (Login.MyMB.Interface.IAmbiente ambiente, Login.MyMB.Lucene.Client.LuceneArticoliSearcher las, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] ListParametri, System.Boolean isAbilitataRicercaBarcode) <0xe47fc0 + 0x000e7> in :0 ...............................

At the link https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations , I found the problem cause (I suppose...):

> Value types as Dictionary Keys Using a value type as a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` key is problematic, as the default Dictionary constructor attempts to use `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default`. `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default`, in turn, attempts to use Reflection to instantiate a new type which implements the `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` interface. This works for reference types (as the reflection+create a new type step is skipped), but for value types it crashes and burns rather quickly once you attempt to use it on the device. 
>   **Workaround:** Manually implement the `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` interface in a new type and provide an instance of that type to the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (`IEqualityComparer<TKey>`) constructor.

### Question

Is there a built-in cross-platform way to create a default `IEqualityComparer<int>`? I am trying to avoid making a class like this

```
private class Int32EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<int>.Equals(int x, int y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<int>.GetHashCode(int obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

just for the sake of getting around this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no implementation of `IEqualityComparer<int>` in .NET Standard as you can determine by searching the [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netstandard-2.0).

If you intend to implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` yourself, it might be worth making a generic implementation with `T` constrained to `IEquatable<T>` so that you cover multitude of types instead of just `int`. All value types are recommended to implement `IEquatable<T>` as per [Framework design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it, [the list of derived types on `IEqualityComparer<T>`'s documentation for .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netstandard-2.0#derived) doesn't list anything for integers.